# IIFE VS anonymous closesure.

Tags: javascript, module, self-invoking-function

Javascript rookie here. While reading module patterns. I noticed this anonymous function which has parenthesis inside function scope. I have not used this before. I'd like to understand it better.

```
// first example
(function(){
    //this is IIFE I always use to avoid globle var. I think the simple form of this is F();
})();

// second example
(function () {
    //However, what is this concept? what's the formal name of this function? 
}());
```

what are major differences between these two? How I understand the second example?

Comment: Do they work exactly same when used for creating or importing module as well? I had this question while I am learning module patterns such as this http://codepen.io/WickyNilliams/pen/DeigH

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some subtle difference (because some validators suggest the second over the first) but functionally they fulfill the same role of executing code immediately in a scope that isn't the global scope.

Comment: They are evaluated exactly the same. Some people just think the second one looks nicer and the first one looks like [dog balls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY#t=2020s)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't need the wrapping parens, if you remove those you'll see it is the same:

```
function(){}()
function(){}()
```

Above, that's an IIFE already.

But if that function is not used as an expression, for example in an assignment, then JavaScript will think it is a function declaration. To disambiguate the code and force an expression you can do various things, like adding parentheses:

```
// Same thing
(function(){}())
(function(){})()
```

Or using a unary operator:

```
!function(){}()
+function(){}()
void function(){}()
```

Comment: You are saying in this case we don't want JavaScript to think function(){}() as an declaration. We want it to treat it as expression, thus we put () on side of it.

Comment: We wrap it in parens to force an expression. The `()` is to execute the function, that's what makes it an IIFE.